# Why am I seeing the 'title' in Web-page's body (Not only in Title Bar)?

Tags: html, hyperlink, stylesheet, title

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run this code, I see 'My Page' in my Browser's Title Bar and in Body too!

Why am I getting this?

Comment: Well [clearly](https://jsfiddle.net/ecr1hbcb/) your main.css looks like: `body:after { content: 'My Page' }`.

Comment: I have cleared everything from main.css - No Problem!
But, when I add `* { display: block; }` I get that. @lc.

Answer (score 4):

Because `<head>` and `<title>` are just tags, like anything else. And the `*` selector picks them up too.

---

For kicks, take a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ecr1hbcb/2/), which clearly demonstrates when you give `head` and `title` a `display:block` style, they indeed show up as text on the page:

HTML

```
<body>
    <p>hi</p>
</body>
```

CSS

```
head, title {display:block}
```

Output

> - jsFiddle demo
>
> hi

---

For a bit more fun, [we can color things too](https://jsfiddle.net/ecr1hbcb/3/). And we even learn something about the inner workings of JSFiddle in the process. It looks like they inline your style in a `<style>` tag inside the `<head>`. Ha!

Comment: reset css is a much better option than `*`.

Comment: yeah, thats true! What if we add `*{color: blue;}` ?

Does that apply to title, head,... tags too ?

Comment: @SathyamoorthyR It's funny you should mention that. Take a look at my last link (https://jsfiddle.net/ecr1hbcb/3/)

Comment: Are meta tags (meta title) also affected the same way? I've never had a meta title show on the page, only in the title bar. Just out of curiosity and for future reference. Thanks.

Comment: That's going crazy ! @lc.

Comment: Oh you beat me to it! Cheers

Answer (score -2):

No. It doesn't and wouldn't output such a result. Have you tried refreshing/clearing the cache of your browser?

Comment: Or did you specify something in main.css? Something like CSS Content (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_content.asp)?

Comment: Yup! I could find the culprit!
I have in main.css,

* { display: block; }

Now, I'm curious what's hapenning?

Comment: display block cannot be a culprit in a game where you are responsible for putting data through css. And you don't have to use `<html>` if you have specified the doctype earlier.

Comment: Okay, I cleared `<html>` , but, still showing ? @SachinKanungo

Comment: can you post css contents of your file, or just for a moment unlink that css and refresh the page

Comment: Please look at the comments in question ! That has an answer @SachinKanungo